# Cannot access with_scope from a mixin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mixins

I just stumbled over a weird problem, and I don't really understand what is causing this.

In our rails app, let's have a mixin `Mixin`:

```
module Mixin
  def foo
    with_scope :find => ... do
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

which is `include`ed into a model class elsewhere:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Mixin
  ...
end
```

calling `Model.new.foo` results in an error: `NoMethodError: undefined method with_scope`

I then changed the `foo` method to:

```
  def foo
    self.class.with_scope :find => ... do
      ...
    end
  end
```

But this also results in an error: `NoMethodError: protected method with_scope called`

This seems odd. I would have expected that the mixin methods would behave like any other method in `Model`. I never stumbled over this before, because all the instance methods like `save` are there and work as usual.

Am I doing it all wrong?

Comment: PS it works using `send(:with_scope, ...)` of course, but this is a hack of course.